# Make particles appeared when colliding with a object

Tags: particles, collision

I wanna make a particle simulation where the particles would appeared when colliding with an object. My setup is this : Particles are being emitted from a plane. Wind is pushing the particles toward an object (a space capsule, I am trying to make a capusle reentry sequence) and the particles are colliding with the capsule making a trail (like in an capsule reentry). My problem is I don't want to see the particles between the time they are emitted from the plane and the time they touch the capsule. So, in brief, how to make the particles visible, only, after they collide with an object? Thanks :)